# Jquery get attributes from different divs with one function

Tags: jquery

I would like to use a single JQ function to get the attributes (dfile) of the different  divs. 
I tried in this way, but I always get the attribute file1.

```
<div class="downlfile" dfile="file1">FILE1</div>
<div class="downlfile" dfile="file2">FILE2</div>
<div class="downlfile" dfile="file3">FILE3</div>
```

JQ

```
$('.downlfile').click(function(){
    var file = $('.downlfile').attr('dfile');
    alert(file);
});
```

How could I do that? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this : use `.each()` to iterate all `div` and read their attribute

```
$('.downlfile').click(function(){
    $('.downlfile').each(function(){
    var file =  $(this).attr('dfile');
    alert(file);
 });
});
```

**Edit** - As OP said, want to show dfile for clicked div. Use below code

```
$('.downlfile').click(function(){
  var file =  $(this).attr('dfile');
  alert(file);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I must get only one var "dfile". If I click on second div I must show only file2.

Comment: Maybe I have to use the ids, but then I do not know how to use a single function.

Comment: You are right that you are using `class` instead of `id`. See my edited answer for showing file attribute for clicked div.